# KMLTree for Using with the Google Earth Plugin

Tags: tree, kml, google-earth-plugin

I need a solution for loading all the layers and elements of a KML file into a webpage tree element for use with the Google Earth Plugin.

Is the jquery KMLTree the only option for a tree to view KML layers and elements with the GE Plugin?

https://code.google.com/p/kmltree/

Answer (score 2):

Author of kmltree here. I'd caution against trying to roll your own with any old treeview control. Parsing kml and dealing with networklinks is a major pain, especially considering that the API gives limited access to the loaded networklinks.

Kmltree had some serious effort and real-world testing put into it for a couple years so it would be a shame not to leverage it. I'm not aware of any other projects that have gone to similar lengths to support networklinks, html (even youtube) infoWindows, and all the particularities of tree styling in the spec. I'm not actively maintaining it anymore since my work has taken my attention elsewhere, but it's still in good shape and patches are always welcome.

Comment: Agreed. My point here is to get a list of all the options so we can begin investigating them for our project. If KMLTree is the only/best option, then that is the one we will look at using.

Comment: OOI I too have made a Kml treeview control that supports network links and networklink controls, but it is for desktop applications rather than websites...I would reiterate what @underbluewaters says - supporting everything is hard! That said most applications don't need 'everything' - if you have an application that requires only a subset of KML then 'rolling your own' can be both a viable and desirable.

Answer (score 0):

No - but to date it is by far the best.

There is this demo is the api samples gallery that Uses dojo for example.

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/dom-tree/index.html

Essentially you could use any treeview control from any framework and adapt it to show Kml features - there are plenty out there.

Also, Kml is just Xml - so it would be fairly easy to build your control that has the functionality you require by using native JavaScript and the Google Earth api.